# Ruby equivalent operators at "OrElse" and "AndAlso" of Vb.net

Tags: ruby, operators

There are operators in Ruby similar to "OrElse"and "AndAlso" in VB.NET?

<strike>For example in Ruby NoMethodError exception is raised when active_record is nil:</strike>

```
if active_record.nil? || active_record.errors.count == 0
     ...
end
```

In VB.net i can do:

```
 If active_record Is Nothing OrElse active_record.errors.count = 0
    ...
 End
```

<strike>That does not generate an exception because it is only checked the first expression</strike>

Comment: is `active_record` in your code the actual library, or an example active_record object?

Comment: in this example active_record is an object that can be nil

Comment: Don't know why you've stroked your phrases. About last one, the correct would be that in VB.NET, second expression is only evaluated if first goes false. [This is short circuit operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), the same thing happening with Ruby `&&` & `||`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case there will be no exception raised (because only the first term in || will be evaluated). However you might be interested in reading about [Object#try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) from ActiveSupport, which can be helpful when dealing with objects that can be nil.

Comment: You're right. There was a problem in my code. Only the first term is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby `||` is [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) operator, so it should evaluate only first condition, therefore your `if` should not raise any exception.

I assume `active_record.nil?` returns boolean `true`.

Answer (score 1):

in ruby, there is a big difference between something that is nil and something that is undefined. Considering the following, from IRB:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :002 > active_record
NameError: undefined local variable or method `active_record' for main:Object
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/jed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :003 > active_record = nil
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :004 > active_record.class
 => NilClass 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :006 > active_record.nil?
 => true
```

So, an object that is nil is an instance of NilClass and therefore responds to the message `nil?` will return true, but without declaring the variable (as in your code) Ruby doesn't know what you are calling.

A couple of options here:

Ruby's `||` operator is a strict operator, whereas the `or` keyword is less strict, so I don't know where the vb operation compares to these two or flow options.

you could use a neat little gem callled '[andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/)'

```
require 'andand'
active_record.andand.errors.count == 0
```

but, generally when you are dealing with this situation in rails, you would use another means to determine the situation above, consider:

```
@post = Post.new(:my_key => "my value") #=> an ActiveRecord object
if @post.valid?
  # do something meaningful
else
  puts @post.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
end
```

and if you mean to assign something based on if it possibly undefined, you would want to use memoization:

```
@post ||= Post.new
```

which will declare the object if undefined or use the existing object